# AudioObjectAddPropertyListenerBlock not called in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, core-audio

I want to observe Audio Device Parameter changes using Swift 3. I look up some info and came to this code. In my viewmodel, I setup a listener block, and the resulting status is 0 (succeeded):

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        addListenerBlock(listenerBlock: audioObjectPropertyListenerBlock,
                         onAudioObjectID: AudioObjectID(bitPattern: kAudioObjectSystemObject),
                         forPropertyAddress: AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
                            mSelector: kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar,
                            mScope: kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
                            mElement: kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster))

    }

    // Utility function to simplify adding listener blocks:
    func addListenerBlock( listenerBlock: @escaping AudioObjectPropertyListenerBlock, onAudioObjectID: AudioObjectID, forPropertyAddress: AudioObjectPropertyAddress) {
        var forPropertyAddress = forPropertyAddress

let status = AudioObjectAddPropertyListenerBlock(onAudioObjectID, &forPropertyAddress, nil, listenerBlock)
        print(status)
    }


    func audioObjectPropertyListenerBlock (numberAddresses: UInt32, addresses: UnsafePointer<AudioObjectPropertyAddress>) {

        var index: UInt32 = 0
        while index < numberAddresses {
            let address: AudioObjectPropertyAddress = addresses[index]
            switch address.mSelector {
            case kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice:

                let deviceID = getDefaultAudioOutputDevice()
                print("kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice: \(deviceID)")

            default:

                print("We didn't expect this!")

            }
            index += 1
        }
    }
        // Utility function to get default audio output device:
        func getDefaultAudioOutputDevice () -> AudioObjectID {

            var devicePropertyAddress = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(mSelector: kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice, mScope: kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal, mElement: kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster)
            var deviceID: AudioObjectID = 0
            var dataSize = UInt32(truncatingBitPattern: MemoryLayout<AudioDeviceID>.size)
            let systemObjectID = AudioObjectID(bitPattern: kAudioObjectSystemObject)
            if (kAudioHardwareNoError != AudioObjectGetPropertyData(systemObjectID, &devicePropertyAddress, 0, nil, &dataSize, &deviceID)) { return 0 }
            return deviceID
    }
```

Yet even though the OSStatus is 0 and the listener is added, it is not called when I change a parameter (in this case, output volume). I set a breakpoint in my audioObjectPropertyListenerBlock but my application never gets there. What did I miss?

Comment: It's incredibly buggy that `AudioObjectAddPropertyListenerBlock` returns no error for an invalid `objectID`/`AudioObjectPropertyAddress` combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems lie here:

```
addListenerBlock(listenerBlock: audioObjectPropertyListenerBlock,
               onAudioObjectID: AudioObjectID(bitPattern: kAudioObjectSystemObject),
                forPropertyAddress: AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
                         mSelector: kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar,
                            mScope: kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
                        mElement: kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster))
```

1. `onAudioObjectID` should be the default output device: `getDefaultAudioOutputDevice()` (these int-ly typed APIs are confusing)
2. `mScope` should be `kAudioObjectPropertyScopeOutput`, and
3. `mElement` should be 1 or 2. (at least my output device doesn't have a master element!)

All together:

```
addListenerBlock(listenerBlock: audioObjectPropertyListenerBlock,
                 onAudioObjectID: getDefaultAudioOutputDevice(),
                 forPropertyAddress: AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
                    mSelector: kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar,
                    mScope: kAudioObjectPropertyScopeOutput,
                    mElement: 1))
```

After these changes, your listener block is called when the left channel output volume is changed.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do in the listener block, however, as `mSelector` is always going to be the `kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar` you requested, and never `kAudioObjectSystemObject`.